# CLion parses GCC errors?

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a few `CMake` targets in my project that calls `makefiles`, which will call `gcc`.

When there is a build error it shows up on Messages>Build:

```
my_dir/my_file.c: In function 'my_func':
my_dir/my_file.c.c:52:5: error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

I wanted to click on it and go straight to `my_dir/my_file.c.c:52:5`, is that possible?

My `Cmakelists.txt` only has symbols and include folders for indexing purposes, no C build configuration since all of that is made in the `makefiles`.

**EDIT**

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` structure:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(myexec)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 99)

set(MakefileDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/make)

add_custom_target(
        mytarget
        ALL
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MakefileDir}
        COMMAND make all)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS *.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDRS *.h)

include_directories(
      sometthing/inc
      (...)
)

add_definitions(
        -DMY_SYM=1
        (...)
)

add_executable(myexec EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
```

Comment: Besides going to the file and line manually, have you thought about converting the old makefiles to also use CMake? Then all the parts of your project would be part of the bigger CLion project automatically.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, not an option here since those makefiles might change (it's not in my control)

Comment: Then perhaps add one or more dummy targets in your `CMakeLists.txt` file listing the source files in those makefiles? So they are part of the project?

Comment: I added the CmakeLists structure. I think they are added this way, no? At least the symbols are recognized in the source files I've used until now